# postcss is not working in combination with webpack 5 and sass

Tags: webpack, sass-loader, postcss-loader

im using webpack 5 and latest css/postcss/sass packages. now im getting the error

```
  Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string
```

If i remove the postcss loader it works.

Thats the code

```
            rules: [{
            test: /\.s?css/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap,
                        url,
                        importLoaders: 1,
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: require('postcss-loader').loader,
                    options: {
                        sourceMap,
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [
                                require('postcss-import')(),
                                require('cssnano')(),
                                require('autoprefixer')(autoprefixerOptions),
                                require('postcss-merge-rules')(),
                                require('postcss-object-fit-images'),
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                }
            ]
        },]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i solved it.

it was

```
loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
```

and not

```
require('postcss-loader').loader
```